# Why isn't there a lengthCompare method on Scala Set?

Tags: scala

In Scala `Seq`, there is a `lengthCompare` method which returns the comparison between the `Seq` length and a given `Int` without computing the length of the `Seq`.

It is implemented in the trait `SeqLike` as follows:

```
/** Compares the length of this $coll to a test value.
   *
   *   @param   len   the test value that gets compared with the length.
   *   @return  A value `x` where
   *   {{{
   *        x <  0       if this.length <  len
   *        x == 0       if this.length == len
   *        x >  0       if this.length >  len
   *   }}}
   *  The method as implemented here does not call `length` directly; its running time
   *  is `O(length min len)` instead of `O(length)`. The method should be overwritten
   *  if computing `length` is cheap.
   */
  def lengthCompare(len: Int): Int = {
    if (len < 0) 1
    else {
      var i = 0
      val it = iterator
      while (it.hasNext) {
        if (i == len) return if (it.hasNext) 1 else 0
        it.next()
        i += 1
      }
      i - len
    }
  }
```

Since this implementation only requires an `iterator`, why isn't it defined in `IterableLike`?

That would make it available in `Seq`, `Set` and `Map` collections.

Comment: I guess one reason is it's just not that common a use-case to need to compare Set or Map lengths for sets or Maps that might be infinite?

Comment: I would guess there is no principled reason, but I'm not 100% sure. @Paul it isn't only about guarding against infinite sets, it's also about exiting early out of the traversal of a finite set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one in the new and greatly overhauled Scala 2.13 collections that was released just yesterday, [see here](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/Iterable.html#sizeCompare(otherSize:Int):Int). The simple reason is that plenty of things about the Scala collections just weren't the way they ought to be, which has now been fixed. The fact that it exists in the new version indicates that it wasn't an active choice to exclude it previously.